# Can JMockit mock constructors with any argument?

Tags: unit-testing, powermock, jmockit

I am replacing PowerMock with JMockit in old unit testing case.
Below is the PowerMock sample code which mock  the File.class  constructors with  any argument .

Can JMockit   mock  constructors  with  any argument like it ?

The situation is this:myFile is a mock. And  I want to simulate returning myFile when calling any constructor in the File class..So What  is the code like.

```
// PowerMock
  whenNew(File.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myfile);

// JMockit
 new Expectations() {{
        new File(anyString);
        result = myfile;
        minTimes = 0;
    }};
```

Comment: Yes, it can, but you wouldn't write the test like that. I can't tell what exactly you're trying to achieve here, however. Is `myfile` a mock or a real `File`? What's the actual need?

Comment: Thank you for your replay.The situation is this: I want to simulate multiple constructors in the File class.So What  is the code like.

Comment: Using `@Mocked AClass` causes all of the constructors in the class to be mocked.

Comment: Now It works.   Thanks again for your inputs !